# which hosting provider is the best suited for the following web frameworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-web-services, laravel, web-hosting

As i have searched through the internet i have been able to find good sites to buy domain such as godaddy, namecheap ..etc . But i havent been able to know which is the best suitable hosting among services such as aws,digital ocean,linode,dreamhost and other provider for apps / websites based on :

1.Ruby on Rails

2.Laravel [php framework]

3.Node.js based frameworks

I basically want to build apps like  :

1. a products listing site with dynamic listing with large databases so the hosting provider should be fast and able to handle and provide options for load balancing and scaling when necessary and easy to use.
2. to be able to store and stream videos via the hosting provider[like amazon s3 service] or any others ,so support for using heavy bandwidth .
3. And to host simple blogs or portfolio sites.

i used to host in godaddy[which has no support for Ruby on rails] so i am planning on changing to another hosting provider . And i am thinking of sites such as namecheap.com , aws , dreamhost , digitalocean , linode or any others.

So kindly guide me which host is better suited for my requirements so that i can run apps/websites based on any of the above frameworks .

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: well i used to host in godaddy but it does provide ruby on rails so i want to switch to another hosting site which has support for all major frameworks and fulfills my above requirements of load balancing and scaling ,because i do not know which is better for those

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion: Amazon is expensive, Hetzner is cheaper if you need more power, DigitalOcean have nice VPS with SSD for 5$, and you can choose data centers in different parts of world.

Recently I use DigitalOcean

For load-balancing and scalability you can use facilities of hosting provider, but it will be cheaper to do by yourself. For example one nginx can serve huge amount of requests, proxy to backends and do load-balancing. If you use VPS

More fancy hosters like Heroku makes scaling easier, but it's not for free...

You may also look at rackspace and google compute engine

Comment: hi thank you ,that was really helpful . so for my needs is it better to go with digital ocean over amazon . And what about namecheap or dreamhost are they not felxible enough for my needs . And  most of the large sites out thr use Aws mostly why is that so .

Comment: For rails and node.js mostly you'll need a VPS, I never try Dreamhost or namecheap. And as I see, price is higher then average. For rails better have 512mb ram or more, node.js can run with lower ram.

Comment: oh k , so what about laravel based apps , the 512 ram is better for running  any one application right . what if i want to run more sites like a blogs or portfolios based website . which hosting is better for those  thank you

Comment: Never used laravel, and it may depends on your configuration: apache + mod_php or nginx + php-fpm. May be you can try with digitalocean, can upgrade any time and billing is per hour. (btw I recommend you to use different companies to buy domains and web-hosting)

Comment: oh k, thank you very much for taking time and answering. One last question , if i wish to host like 2 to 4 sites , is it better to go with a shared hosting or a vps . And if shared hosting which one do u suggest is good enough to do the job and has support for all 3 frameworks that i had mentioned.

Comment: I don't know, never used rails or node.js on shared hosting, don't have such experience